# JQuery checking multiple inputs and select values

Tags: jquery

looking for some pointers to work with JQuery.

I have three form elements:

select - id: lodge 
input[text] - id: dates
select - id: duration

What I need to do is cause a function to run if any of these either has a change or blur, but also for the script to check that each has a value and to pass all three of those values to the script.

So I need to populate three variables:

```
var LodgeChoice = $('#lodge').val();
                var DateParse = $('#dates').datepicker('getDate');
                var DateChosen = DateParse.getFullYear() + '-' + (DateParse.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + DateParse.getDate();
                var Duration = $('#durationNights').val();
```

But I cannot be sure what order someone will populate the form variables.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#lodge, #dates, #durationNights").on("blur change", function() {
    //get/process values here
});
```

If you need to know which element was changed for some reason, you can refer to `$(this)` from inside the event handler function

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment: If you also need to make sure all three have a value before proceeding, you don't have to just have a big if statement. Instead, you can do the following:

```
var fields = $("#lodge, #dates, #durationNights");
fields.on("blur change", function() {
    var valuesSet = true;
    fields.each(function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) { //inside a jQuery "each", "this" refers to the current item in the loop
            valuesSet = false;
            return false; //break out of the "each" loop
        }
    });
    if (valuesSet) {
        //process values
    }
});
```

Comment: this sets up the blur event bind so whenever a user deselects one of those fields it will run your anonymous callback. 
inside the callback use

$(this).val(); to grab the value of whichever one of the elements was just deselected by the client.

Comment: Isn't that what he wanted? "cause a function to run if any of these either has a change or blur"

Comment: yeah and that's why i gave you an upvote. I just wanted to clarify a little further because many people have difficulty with the scope of $(this). if you think about the scenario, if you bind the same blur event and handler to all of the elements, then inside the handler you need to identify which element you should grab the value of and IMO the most efficient approach is to use this when setting the variables.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I actually need to check that all three elements have a value before progressing the script.  But I guess a simple if else would work and just iterate over each element, until all 3 if/else statements are filled.